# What was so miraculous of the Chanukah war?

Tags: history, chanuka, army-military-war, masecheth-avodah-zarah

In the Chanukah "Al Hanisim", it says: "You delivered the mighty into the hands of the weak, the many into the hands of the few, the impure into the hands of the pure, the wicked into the hands of the righteous, and the wanton sinners into the hands of those who occupy themselves with Your Torah."

But the Romans helped the Jews? As the Gemara [Avodah Zara 8b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.8b.5?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) says:

> דכי אתא רב דימי אמר תלתין ותרין קרבי עבדו רומאי בהדי יונאי ולא יכלו להו עד דשתפינהו לישראל בהדייהו והכי אתנו בהדייהו אי מינן מלכי מנייכו הפרכי אי מנייכו מלכי מינן הפרכי
>
> The Gemara elaborates: As when Rav Dimi came from Eretz Yisrael he said: The Romans waged thirty-two battles with the Greeks but were unable to defeat them, until they formed a partnership with the Jewish people and finally vanquished the Greeks. And this is the condition that they stipulated with the Jewish people: If the kings come from among us, the governors [hiparkhei] will come from among you; and if the kings come from among you, the governors will come from among us.

So while the Gemara implies that the Romans wouldn't have been victorious on their own, they definitely *helped* the Jews.

So do we say that Hashem gave "the many into the hands of the few" when it wasn't just Us vs. the Greeks but Us + Rome vs. the Greeks?

Comment: So the war can't still be a miracle since the Romans helped the Hasmoneans? I'm not following.

Comment: @ezra it's not **the mighty into the hands of the weak, the many into the hands of the few**

Comment: Chanukah celebrates the reconquering and re-dedication of the Beis Hamikdash. This happened at the beginning of the rebellion against the Greeks, and before the Romans got involved. The war continued for years after the story of Chanukah. -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman%E2%80%93Jewish_Treaty

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: I don't think the change in your question affects my answer. Al Hanisim is celebrating a victory that took place before the Romans got involved.

Comment: Also much of the references are not about the Romans but about the Hellenists who were the main adversaries. The miracle was defeating the Hellenists who actively fought on the side of the Greeks and the destruction of their ideology which allowed the Jewish people to survive.

Comment: The Romans had been fighting (and beating) the Greeks before the rebellion. In the Treaty of Apamea, 20 years before the rebellion, selucids psid the Romans a huge indemnity (15000 talents) and had to severely limit their navy and give up a lot of territory and all his elephants. Antiochus III had to loot his own temples to keep country afloat.

Comment: @Menachem Sounds like an answer...

Comment: Another source (besides that in the Gemara like you mentioned) for the Jews making an alliance to fend of the Greeks is I Maccabees 8:17-20.